# add css class to the form (Yii form builder)

Tags: css, yii, yii-cform

How can we add css class or id to the form element which has been created by Yii form bui
Imagine that I have created a form as follows:

**Controller:**

```
public function actionRegistration()
{

    $form = new CForm('application.views.user.registerForm');
    $form['user']->model = new Users;
    $form['profile']->model = new Profile;

    if(isset($_POST['Users']))
    {
        $form['profile']->model->attributes = $_POST['Profile'];
        $_POST['Users']['mobile'] = $_POST['Profile']['mobile'];
        $form['user']->model->attributes = $_POST['Users'];

        if($form->validate()) {
            $user = $form['user']->model;
            $profile = $form['profile']->model;
            if($profile->save(false))
            {
                $user->profile_id = $profile->id;
                $user->save(false);
            }
        }
        else {
            $errors = array_merge($form['profile']->model->errors, $form['user']->model->errors);
        }
    }

    $this->render('registration', array('form'=>$form));
}
```

**View**

```
    <?php echo $form->renderBegin(); ?>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="nine columns">
            <div class="field">
                <?php echo $form['profile']['fname']; ?>
            </div>
            <div class="field">
                <?php echo $form['profile']['lname']; ?>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="eight columns">
                    <div class="field phone">
                        <?php echo $form['profile']['phone']; ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="eight columns">
                    <div class="field mobile">
                        <?php echo $form['profile']['mobile']; ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="eight columns">
                    <div class="field password">
                        <?php echo $form['user']['pass']; ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="field address email">
                <input type="text" name="Users[email]" value="" placeholder="Email" class="text input">
            </div>
        </div>


    </div>
    <div class="row text-center margins">
        <span class="medium warning btn">
            <button type="submit"Submit</button>
        </span>
    </div>
    <?php echo $form->renderEnd(); ?>
```

I want to set an id or a class for my form element which is generated by $form->renderBegin() function. I don't know how to add any html options to the form. Please someone help me.

Comment: If this is the structure that will always be produced you could pretty easily use jQuery to add a class onto it.

Comment: I wanna know that how is it possible to add any htmlOption to the form element, not necessary a class or id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your view file before renderBegin make assignment for attributes:

```
<?php 
  $form->attributes= array('id'=>'el123', 'class'=>'qwe');
  echo $form->renderBegin(); ?>
```